# MySQL: STR_TO_DATE with YYWW

Tags: mysql, date, date-format, str-to-date

How do you use MySQL with YYWW instead of YYYYWW?

My field looks like this:

`wYYWW, for example w1310, w1506` and so on.

`%x` and `%X` seems to need 4 digits, and therefor it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about stuffing the characters you need into the string?  Something like this:

```
select str_to_date(insert(col, 1, 1, '20'), '%X%u')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for! :) (not exactly, since I thought that there was some %x that looked like %y instead of %Y, but it solved the problem! :) )